# Progressive fixture in scalatest

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm new to scalatest, so I hope this isn't obvious but...

I'm trying so far unsuccessfully to build tests in what I would think is a common design pattern: I'm testing the initialization of an object, and I'd like each step of the process to be a separate test.  Since some of those tests have side effects elsewhere in the system (like launching a spark cluster), that can interfere with other tests, I don't want each test to have to repeat what took place in the prior tests. Instead, id like to create an object in the first test, keep the same instance in the additional tests, execute them in sequence, and stop executing the spec if one fails.

I understand that usually the way to do something like this is to put initialization and destruction code into the fixture or mixin BeforeAndAfter. That's great, but in this case initialization and destruction are precisely what I'm trying to test, and they're complex multi-step processes.

I tried doing this with fixtures, but scalatest apparently wants to create a new instance of the fixture for each test. It also doesn't seem to guarantee that the tests will be executed in the same sequence, not in parallel. And, running from maven, doesn't seem to guarantee that only one spec will be run at a time.

Surely others must have dealt with similar issues before?

EDIT:  here's some sample code

```
class MinimalExample extends fixture.FlatSpec {

  case class FixtureParam(var thingy: String)

  def withFixture(test: OneArgTest) = {
    val tester = new FixtureParam(null)
    withFixture(test.toNoArgTest(tester))
  }

  "Creating a minimally reproducible example" should "start with creating a String" in { fixture =>
    val command = "A string"
    fixture.thingy = command
    fixture.thingy shouldBe a [String]
  }

  it should "still be a String in this second test" in { fixture =>
    val command = fixture.thingy
    assert(command != null)
  }
  it should "still be a String we mean it!!!" in { fixture =>
    fixture.thingy shouldBe a [String]
  }
}
```

I'd expect all three tests to produce the same result.  Instead, test 1 passes.  Test 2 fails with null == null.  Test 3 throws a null pointer exception.

Comment: So your problem is that the tests are not executed in the order you declared them, or run in parallel?

Comment: Really that multiple specs seem to be run at the same time, and that the fixtures doesn't seem persistent within a spec. What's happening in many cases is something like this: the fixture is initially created with var fields set to null. The first test creates an object and assigns it to a var in the fixture. The second test wants to access that var field and perform an operation on the object created in the first test. The first test will run fine but the second throws a NullPointerException when it tries to access the object.

Comment: Another thing I'm seeing, is that logging output from the creation of the fixture gets emitted for each and every test, when it should only have been emitted when  the fixture was created for the first test.

Comment: Could you specify which suite are you using and perhaps add some sample code?

Comment: Flatspec or fixture Flatspec. I can try to add sample code tonight but it's going to be pretty illegible without the stuff actually being tested.

Comment: You mentioned *Spec*  does that mean that you are suing *Specs2*?